# Send Text or Keys to external Program

Tags: java, string, key, external

Is it possible to inject text or keys into an external program via Java.

For Example i have the standard Windows Editor open, can i send from my java programm "Hello World" to it. And then the Editor would content "Hello World" and then again sending STRG +S to save it etc.

Thx

Comment: Some programs will allow you to pass in various bits of data using a proper format (e.g. like command line arguments, or IO streams). If you are looking to inject directly/forcibly I think you might be looking into something more complex (e.g. editing things outside the JVM).

Answer (score 1):

**You can not make a program in any language which can control the internal functionality of an another application. But, if you still want to do that then use one of the following approaches:**

1. Make your own text editor Windows application which will be acting as a client to a socket server made by your External java application. listen the message sent by the server and show it into the work-space & define a keyword which will be treated differently from a normal message (e.g saveItNow) to perform save task.
2. Make a simple text file suppose "test.txt". Open cmd and type `tail -f test.txt` in the same directory. Now by simple java file handling you can save text to test.txt and immediately it will be shown in the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Robot Class could be a solution for me...

```
String text = "Hello World from the Clipboard :)";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

But how can i handle to set the focus on the extern programm first?
(except Moving the Mouse to the Window and click on It with robot.mouseMove(x,y))